# I'm not sure why this code isn't compiling, it requires a non-static variable

Tags: java, class, static, program-entry-point, void

```
class TheAnimal {

    public class Animal {
        void bark(){
            System.out.println("Woof-Woof");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Animal dog = new Animal();
         dog.bark();
    }

}
```

// Keeps saying on line 12 Animal dog = new Animal(); after compiling that it's a non-static variable and that it cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Your `main` method is outside of your class body. Put it back in there.

Comment: A decent formatting may reveal the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You created an inner class Animal which can only be instantiated in a outer class instance context (which is probably not what you want/need now). Declare your inner class as static will let you instanciated it as you think:

```
class TheAnimal {   
    static public class Animal {
        void bark(){
            System.out.println("Woof-Woof");
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Animal dog = new Animal();
         dog.bark();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You inner class `Animal` requires an instance of `TheAnimal`, make it `static`.

```
public static class Animal {
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Woof-Woof");
    }
}
```

Or, you need an instance of `TheAnimal` in `main`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal dog = new TheAnimal().new Animal();
    dog.bark();
}
```